# "robustest" Why do all grammar software underline this word?

Tags: grammaticality, sentence

I wrote a sentence like the following using the word "robustest". But many grammar software started showing typos. The word exists in the dictionary. Why is this happening? I came across it in an article I wrote using American English. Thank you for your valuable feedback.

> Finally, classifier models are produced. Performance tests are performed on models and the robustest model is tried to be synthesized.

Comment: Do not trust grammar checkers. They often make errors. Robustest is a word, according to [Oxford Dictionaries](https://www.lexico.com/definition/robust).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Well, ok, but it’s a terrible word and I can’t think of a real situation where changing to “*most robust*” wouldn’t be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They want you to use "most robust".

Most multi-syllable superlatives don't take "-est", but rather use "most ____". https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2018/07/comparative-superlative.html